# Beamer: Pausing before the first item in itemize[<+->]

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

In Beamer, `\begin{itemize}[<+->]` causes items to appear one-by-one. However, item 1 is visible starting from the first slide itself. Is there a way to insert a pause before the first item too?

of course I can manually type

```
\item<2-> first
\item<3-> second
...
```

but is there a shortcut way to specify this?

Comment: You could put an explicit `\pause` before the `itemize` environment.  Would that suffice?

Comment: Hey, thanks! That works. For some reason, I thought pause was only allowed before `\item`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simply write `\pause` before the itemize environment.  This will achieve the effect you want.

Comment: If you have other elements after the `itemize` which should be seen right from the beginning, the method by Mitja is preferable.

Answer (score 22):

As described by Lionel Mansuy in [this duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86678) of this question, the following also works:
`\begin{itemize}[<+(1)->]`

Note that all `<+->` tokens on the same slide also need to be replaced by `<+(1)->` for this to work properly.