# Beamer: uncovering itemize so the first slide shows no items at all

Tags: beamer, counters, overlays

How can I achieve in `beamer` that the first slide of each frame is void (that is, only displays the frametitle)?

Suppose I have the following frame:

```
\frame{\frametitle{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> A
\item<2-> B
\end{itemize}
}
```

Now I want to achieve that on the first slide only the title is displayed and the overlays already specified are accordingly shifted by one (without changing the overlay numbers already specified).

The background is that I have already specified many overlays. Adding +1 to all overlay numbers manually would be a nuisance. Hence I want to tell beamer at the beginning of each frame that it shall pause one slide before starting with the already existing overlays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution to my problem: Insert a void frame:

```
\frame{\frametitle{Title}
}
\frame{\frametitle{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> A
\item<2-> B
\end{itemize}
}
```

PS: This answer implies that my question was not very bright. Please tell me if you agree. I could then delete it.

Comment: I think someone else might find this question useful. Indeed, even though your solution is simple, as it was not immediately obvious to you, chances are that it will not be obvious to others either. So I suggest keeping it!

Comment: OK, maybe we could find a better fitting title so that it will be found by people having the same problem...?!

Comment: I would personally favour keeping the question general. It may be possible to hack `beamer`'s decoding of the overlay number to achieve what you originally wanted, and I would be quite interested to see an answer that attempts that. In fact, the current title may in some ways be more obvious to people having the same problem (though that would depend on what alternative titles can be proposed). Ultimately, I guess it's up to you, unless anyone else expresses an opinion.

Comment: This may be a very bad solution depending on which outer theme you use. For instance, `\insertframenumber` won't work as you would expect.

Answer (score 24):

To increase the overlay counter manually (your title), use:

```
\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{X}
```

where `X` is the number of frames... or

```
\stepcounter{beamerpauses}
```

to increment the counter by 1

For example, you proceed like this:

```
\begin{frame}
\stepcounter{beamerpauses}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Another possibility is to set the overlay number by hand:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<2-> A
\item<3-> B
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

**Edit:** it seems also possible to use this kind of construction that could fit to your purpose:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+(1)->]
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

or this:

```
\begin{frame}[<+(1)->]
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Somehow your solutions don't achieve what I intended ... I edited my question. Now it should be clearer what I had in mind ...

Comment: Sorry, but IMO it is not possible: adding `\item<1->` tells explicitly to beamer to display this part from slide 1. You have either to fix all your numbers, or to use incremental displaying (<+-> and co) that will be more flexible in case of modification.

Comment: @lpdbw Changing all your overlay numeration could be more or less easy, depending on your editor. I've never done it, but editor like `VIM` have powerfull search/replace capabilities and I'm pretty sure that it could recognize the syntax `<(num)->` and replace it automatically by `<(num+1)->`...

Comment: My editor is WinEdt V5 ... VIM is out of my league! ;-) But, you could be right that my problem has no solution since I assign an absolute value to the overlay counters ...

Comment: `<+(1)->` saved my ass. When I tried using `\pause` before the item list, the pictured that came after the list was also paused — with this overlay specification, it's not.

Comment: Note that if you use `\begin{enumerate}[<+(1)->]` with the `enumerate` package and want to customise the labels, you have to write `\begin{enumerate}[<+(1)->][a)]`.

Comment: Wow, didn't know you could do (something like) ``\begin{frame}[<1->]``, the Google never told me!

Answer (score 4):

How about using \only?

```
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\only<2->{
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the interpretation of the overlay specifications, one could consider changing the first overlay number of frames. Note this is almost certainly not a good idea, but I'm offering it as a suggestion anyway.

Also, this affects all frames, not just one. There's probably things I've missed and other undesirable side-effects, but here we go:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcount\beamer@startslidenum
\beamer@startslidenum=0\relax
\patchcmd{\beamer@doseveralframes}{\beamer@slideinframe=1\relax}{\beamer@slideinframe=\beamer@startslidenum}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\patchcmd{\beamer@dosingleframe}{\beamer@slideinframe=1\relax}{\beamer@slideinframe=\beamer@startslidenum}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\patchcmd{\beamer@donoframe}{\beamer@slideinframe=1\relax}{\beamer@slideinframe=\beamer@startslidenum}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> A
\item<2-> B
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do commands like <handout:0> still work ?

Comment: @LionelMANSUY: it depends what you mean by "work" in this context. The normal behaviour of `<handout:0>` is to suppress the frame in the handout mode, and that behaviour is preserved. Whether that is "correct" is another matter. But note that this hack is likely to break almost everything and I don't recommend it be used!