# Automatic readjustment of the order of the display of items

Tags: beamer, itemize

I use the following code to display items sequentially

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
 \frametitle{}
{\textcolor {blue}{\Large {Items on a List}}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item<2>
{item 1}
\item<3>
{item 2}
\item<4>
{item 3}
\item<5>
{item 4}
\item<6>
{item 5}
\item<7>
{item 6}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

When making a list using `enumerate` environment, their numbering is adjusted automatically; and when adding new items in the middle, their numbering is re-adjusted automatically.

When displaying these items sequentially, I use  `\item<2>{...}`, `\item<3>{...}` and so on. But, when I need to insert new items in the middle of the list (for example, when adding an item between 4 and 5), I have to re-adjust the order of the display of each subsequent item.

Is there a way to make the order of their display re-adjusted automatically as their numbering is re-adjusted automatically.

Comment: samcarter or another beamer expert can give you a more authoritative answer, but there is `\item<+>` which looks suspiciously like it could help you.

Comment: You can also use `\begin{enumerate}[<+->]` and then just regular `\item` commands.

Comment: Or even better: `\begin{enumerate}[<+>]
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\item item 4
\item item 5
\item item 6
\end{enumerate}` possibly with `\stepcounter{beamerpauses}` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86678/35864

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give the `enumerate` environment an `<+->` overlay specification like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
 \frametitle{}
{\textcolor {blue}{\Large {Items on a List}}}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\item item 4
\item item 5
\item item 6
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively if you want only the current item to show, you can use `<+>` as specification as mentioned by @moewe:

[image]

In the latter I used `\pause` before the `\begin{enumerate}` to make the first sheet empty:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
 \frametitle{}
{\textcolor {blue}{\Large {Items on a List}}}
\pause
\begin{enumerate}[<+>]
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\item item 4
\item item 5
\item item 6
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the OP only wants `<+>` and not `<+->`, at least that is what the MWE shows. And in their example the first slide is empty, but I don't know if that is a requirement.

Comment: @moewe You are right, I must've overlooked that! I adjusted the answer accordingly.

Comment: +1 But I think it would be a nice touch to add the code for the second output as well. That makes it easier for people looking for a copy-and-paste solution.

Comment: @moewe Again, you are right :)

Comment: Thank you very much; this is what I wanted. Just one comment, instead of using \pause before the \begin{enumerate}, I used  \begin{enumerate}[<+(1)>]